# How to store a list of select component in an state array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, frontend, state

I have a table contains for example 10 rows, each row has a select component.

How can i store all selected items from the all 10 rows in an array in state to be like that `[{"cid":11,"id":2},{"cid":11,"id":3}]` ??

I did it here https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-shannon-sewln but with a small issue.. when i select a choice it always adds to the array even if the same row has a previous choice..

I need the new choice for the same row to over-right the old choice not to add a new record

Comment: Could you use an object instead of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `onSelectGrade`, Create array of item with id and value. On change, check if the same item exist(meaning selected before) then update else create a new one(push in the array).

checkout working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-feather-cl0by

```
onSelectGrade(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    const selectedGrades = [...this.state.selectedGrades];
    const grade = selectedGrades.find(x => x.id === e.target.id);
    if (grade) grade.value = e.target.value;
    else selectedGrades.push({ id: e.target.id, value: e.target.value });
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedGrades
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{}` as your state value and then format this to your required format (i.e. array)

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hopper-ov10z

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedGrades: {}
    };
    this.onSelectGrade = this.onSelectGrade.bind(this);
  }
  onSelectGrade(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedGrades: {
          ...this.state.selectedGrades,
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        }
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }

  getOuput = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.state.selectedGrades).map(key => {
      console.log(key);
      return { id: key, cid: this.state.selectedGrades[key]};
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("required output", this.getOuput());
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select
                defaultValue="Default"
                id="22"
                onChange={this.onSelectGrade}
              >
                <option disabled value="Default">
                  Choose grade
                </option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">c</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select
                defaultValue="Default"
                id="23"
                onChange={this.onSelectGrade}
              >
                <option disabled value="Default">
                  Choose grade
                </option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">c</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select
                defaultValue="Default"
                id="24"
                onChange={this.onSelectGrade}
              >
                <option disabled value="Default">
                  Choose grade
                </option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">c</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select
                defaultValue="Default"
                id="25"
                onChange={this.onSelectGrade}
              >
                <option disabled value="Default">
                  Choose grade
                </option>
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">c</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works fine, but if i need to store more than 2 items like ```[{"cid":11,"id":2, "value":test}]``` How can i do that?